# Locating fragments of non-Latin-1 text in a mostly-Latin-1 file?

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, latin1

I believe an English .txt to be Latin-1, but it may contain fragments in another encoding. Are there libraries or tools to locate these fragments?

I'm aware of things like the Python `chardat` library, but I'm specifically looking for a tool to test a Latin-1 file and detect anomalies. Even a regular detection library would be fine, if it's able to tell me the point where it detected a non Latin-1 pattern and give me the index.

Command line tools and Python libraries are especially welcome.

Comment: I feel your pain, have you tried something like [enca](http://linux.die.net/man/1/enca)?

Comment: Enca looks perfect, but bizarrely, it doesn't seem to support English. Just a bunch of Eastern European languages. Really weird, since there are extensive docs in English.

Comment: Could you give examples of anomalies? Are you looking for UTF8 or some other 8-bit character set? Code points 0x80-0x9F are undefined in Latin but otherwise, all sequences are valid. If you are looking for something like KOI-8r mixed with Latin, lettter frequencies and n-gram letter sequences are a good heuristic, but there is no way to know for sure for every individual character.

Comment: For English, you could tolerate any individual 8-bit character surrounded by 7-bit, maybe flag for manual inspection any short sequence of adjacent 8-bit characters, and default to non-English any longer sequences of 8-bit data.

Comment: Have you considered inflicting pain on the person who generated the file?

Answer (score 0):

Latin-1 (or maybe you mean its latin-15 variant with euro sign?) is not that easy to detect.

Simple approach could be to check if some unused characters are actually being used 
(see table [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-15)) - if there are, something is wrong. However, to detect more subtle violations, one needs to actually check if the language is one of those, for which latin-1 is used. Otherwise, there is no way to distinguish between 8-bit encodings. Its much better to never mix 8-bit encodings in the first place, without marking the change of encoding in some way...

Answer (score 0):

What are the grounds for your beliefs that is file (1) is Latin-1 (2) may contain fragments in another encoding? How large is the file? What is a "regular detection library"? Have you considered the possibility that it might be a Windows encoding e.g. cp1252?

Some broad-brush diagnostics:

```
# preliminaries
text = open('the_file.txt', 'rb').read()
print len(text), "bytes in file"

# How many non-ASCII bytes?
print sum(1 for c in text if c > '\x7f'), "non-ASCII bytes"

# Will it decode as UTF-8 OK?
try:
    junk = text.decode('utf8')
    print "utf8 decode OK"
except UnicodeDecodeError, e:
    print e

# Runs of more than one non-ASCII byte are somewhat rare in single-byte encodings
# of languages written in a Latin script ...
import re
runs = re.findall(r'[\x80-\xff]+', text)
nruns = len(runs)
print nruns, "runs of non-ASCII bytes"
if nruns:
    avg_rlen = sum(len(run) for run in runs) / float(nruns)
    print "average run length: %.2f bytes" % avg_rlen
# then if indicated you could write some code to display runs in context ...
```